# Applying mutate_at conditionally to specific rows in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements, tidyverse

I have a dataframe in R that looks like the following:

```
a  b  c  condition
1  4  2  acap
2  3  1  acap
2  4  3  acap
5  6  8  ncap
5  7  6  ncap
8  7  6  ncap
```

I am trying to recode the values in columns a, b, and c for condition ncap (and also 2 other conditions not pictured here) while leaving the values for acap alone.

The following code works when applied to the first 3 columns. I am trying to figure out how I can apply this only to rows that I specify by condition while keeping everything in the same dataframe.

```
df = df %>%
     mutate_at(vars(a:c), function(x) 
     case_when x == 5 ~ 1, x == 6 ~ 2, x == 7 ~ 3, x == 8 ~ 4)
```

This is the expected output.

```
a  b  c  condition
1  4  2  acap
2  3  1  acap
2  4  3  acap
1  2  4  ncap
1  3  2  ncap
4  3  2  ncap
```

I've looked around for an answer to this question and am unable to find it. If someone knows of an answer that already exists, I would appreciate being directed to it.

Comment: Try using `ifelse` on `row_number()`  Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Where would that fit into the pipe? I tried using an ifelse function but didn't know where to put it. And why on row_number() as opposed to using specific values for the "condition" column?

Comment: Or may be `df %>% mutate_at(vars(a:c), funs(case_when(row_number() %in% 4:6 ~ . - 4L, TRUE ~ .)))`

Comment: What does this part mean: 4:6 ~ . - 4L, TRUE ~ .  I know 4:6 are the row numbers but I am confused by the rest.

Comment: If  l look at the pattern, you are replacing the values by taking the difference of the value with 4 for the rows 4:6. i.e. 5-4 = 1, 6-4 =2, 7 -4 =3, and 8-4=4

Comment: Is there a way to do this based on the values specified in condition, or do you think row number is best? Asking since my original df is much larger, so I can find the row numbers, but it's a little more tedious.

Comment: In that case, just replace the row_number() with `. %in% 5:8`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use the `case_when` on a condition created with `row_number` i.e. if the row number is 4 to 6, subtract 4 from the value or else return the value

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(a:c), funs(case_when(row_number() %in% 4:6 ~ . - 4L, 
                                       TRUE ~ .)))
#  a b c condition
#1 1 4 2      acap
#2 2 3 1      acap
#3 2 4 3      acap
#4 1 2 4      ncap
#5 1 3 2      ncap
#6 4 3 2      ncap
```

---

If this is based on the value instead of the rows, create the condition on the value

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(a:c), funs(case_when(. %in% 5:8 ~ . - 4L, 
                                       TRUE ~ .)))
#  a b c condition
#1 1 4 2      acap
#2 2 3 1      acap
#3 2 4 3      acap
#4 1 2 4      ncap
#5 1 3 2      ncap
#6 4 3 2      ncap
```

---

Or if it is based on the value in the 'condition'

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(a:c), funs(case_when(condition == 'ncap' ~ . - 4L, 
                                       TRUE ~ .)))
```

---

Or without using any `case_when`

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(a:c), funs( . - c(0, 4)[(condition == 'ncap')+1]))
#  a b c condition
#1 1 4 2      acap
#2 2 3 1      acap
#3 2 4 3      acap
#4 1 2 4      ncap
#5 1 3 2      ncap
#6 4 3 2      ncap
```

---

In `base R`, we can do this by creating the index

```
i1 <- df$condition =='ncap'
df[i1, 1:3] <- df[i1, 1:3] - 4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 8L), b = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 
 6L, 7L, 7L), c = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 6L), condition = c("acap", 
 "acap", "acap", "ncap", "ncap", "ncap")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: When trying to use the 3rd option, I get this error: "Evaluation error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types." Is there somewhere I can put "as.numeric()" to make it work?

Comment: @melbez  Please check the class of the columns.  I have `character` and numeric column (as showed in the dput)

Comment: What does the ~ . that is repeated twice in the 3rd option mean?

Comment: @melbez `.` represents the value in each column.  With `mutate_at/mutate_all`, it is looping through the columns.  Here, the condition in `case_when` is `if` 'condition' value is 'ncap', then return the value `.`  subtracted from 4 or else return the value `TRUE ~ .`.  You can have many conditions in `case_when` (just as you showed).  Based on the pattern, I reduced some of the steps to subtract 4.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `filter` to apply recoding values to only specific rows (not equal to "acap" here)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(condition != "acap") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(a:c), function(x) 
  case_when(x == 5 ~ 1, x == 6 ~ 2, x == 7 ~ 3, x == 8 ~ 4)) 

#  a b c condition
#1 1 2 4      ncap
#2 1 3 2      ncap
#3 4 3 2      ncap
```

---

If you need the entire dataframe back again we can do

```
df %>%
  filter(condition == "acap") %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%
     filter(condition != "acap") %>%
     mutate_at(vars(a:c), function(x) 
    case_when(x == 5 ~ 1, x == 6 ~ 2, x == 7 ~ 3, x == 8 ~ 4)))

#  a b c condition
#1 1 4 2      acap
#2 2 3 1      acap
#3 2 4 3      acap
#4 1 2 4      ncap
#5 1 3 2      ncap
#6 4 3 2      ncap
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this that allows me to keep everything in the same dataframe?