# Using dplyr::mutate_at with case_when conditional on another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lifecycle

I want to transform a set of variables differently depending on a condition. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940709/applying-mutate-at-conditionally-to-specific-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-r)

Example: I want to substract 4 from all variables 'mpg' to 'disp' if 'gear' equals 4, otherwise I substract 3.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(mpg:disp),
            funs(case_when(gear == 4 ~ . - 4L, TRUE ~ . -3L)))
```

But I get this warning:

```
funs() is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0
Please use a list of either functions or lambdas: 

# Simple named list: 
`list(mean = mean, median = median)`
# Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: 
`tibble::lst(mean, median)`
# Using lambdas
`list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))`

This warning is displayed once per session.
```

Is there a better solution to my problem that avoids using `funs()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

repro do so

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(mpg:disp), ~ case_when(gear == 4 ~ . - 4L, TRUE ~ . -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you. That was such a simple fix that I haven't come up with myself.