# R mutate_at on a subset of rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

My question is similar to this post([Applying mutate_at conditionally to specific rows in a dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940709/applying-mutate-at-conditionally-to-specific-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-r)), and I could reproduce the result. But whey I tried to apply this to my problem, which is putting parenthesis to the cell value for selected rows and columns, I run into error messages. Here's a reproducible example.

```
df <- structure(list(dep = c("cyl", "cyl", "disp", "disp", "drat", 
"drat", "hp", "hp", "mpg", "mpg"), name = c("estimate", "t_stat", 
"estimate", "t_stat", "estimate", "t_stat", "estimate", "t_stat", 
"estimate", "t_stat"), dat1 = c(1.151, 6.686, 102.902, 12.107, 
-0.422, -5.237, 37.576, 5.067, -5.057, -8.185), dat2 = c(1.274, 
8.423, 106.429, 12.148, -0.394, -5.304, 38.643, 6.172, -4.843, 
-10.622), dat3 = c(1.078, 5.191, 103.687, 7.79, -0.194, -2.629, 
36.777, 4.842, -4.539, -7.91)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Given above data frame, I hope to put parenthesis to the cell values of column `dat1`, `dat2` and `dat3`when `name == t_stat`. Here's what I've tried, but it seems like that `paste0` is not accepted inside of the `case_when` function in this case.

```
require(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("dat")), 
+                  funs( case_when(name == 't_stat' ~ paste0("(", ., ")"), TRUE ~ .) )) 
Error: must be a character vector, not a double vector
```

When I use brute force, namely mutate each column, then it works but my actual problem has more than 10 columns so this is not really practical.

```
require(tidyverse)
> df %>%   mutate(dat1 = ifelse(name == "t_stat", paste0("(", dat1, ")"), dat1),
+                 dat2 = ifelse(name == "t_stat", paste0("(", dat2, ")"), dat1),
+                 dat3 = ifelse(name == "t_stat", paste0("(", dat3, ")"), dat1))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   dep   name     dat1     dat2      dat3    
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   
 1 cyl   estimate 1.151    1.151     1.151   
 2 cyl   t_stat   (6.686)  (8.423)   (5.191) 
 3 disp  estimate 102.902  102.902   102.902 
 4 disp  t_stat   (12.107) (12.148)  (7.79)  
 5 drat  estimate -0.422   -0.422    -0.422  
 6 drat  t_stat   (-5.237) (-5.304)  (-2.629)
 7 hp    estimate 37.576   37.576    37.576  
 8 hp    t_stat   (5.067)  (6.172)   (4.842) 
 9 mpg   estimate -5.057   -5.057    -5.057  
10 mpg   t_stat   (-8.185) (-10.622) (-7.91)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when` is type-strict meaning it expects output to be of same class. Your original columns are of type numeric whereas while adding `"("` around your data you are making it of class character.

Also `funs` is long deprecated and `mutate_at` will soon be replaced with `across`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(matches("dat")), 
      ~case_when(name == 't_stat' ~ paste0("(", ., ")"), TRUE ~ as.character(.)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to convert `dbl` to `char` first, and that is what the error message is also saying `Error: must be a character vector, not a double vector`

As @Rohan rightly said, *case_when is type-strict* meaning it expects output to be of same class.

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("dat")),
                 ~case_when(name =='t_stat'~ paste0("(",as.character(.x),")"),
                            T ~ as.character(.x))
                 )
```

output as

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   dep   name     dat1     dat2      dat3    
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   
 1 cyl   estimate 1.151    1.274     1.078   
 2 cyl   t_stat   (6.686)  (8.423)   (5.191) 
 3 disp  estimate 102.902  106.429   103.687 
 4 disp  t_stat   (12.107) (12.148)  (7.79)  
 5 drat  estimate -0.422   -0.394    -0.194  
 6 drat  t_stat   (-5.237) (-5.304)  (-2.629)
 7 hp    estimate 37.576   38.643    36.777  
 8 hp    t_stat   (5.067)  (6.172)   (4.842) 
 9 mpg   estimate -5.057   -4.843    -4.539  
10 mpg   t_stat   (-8.185) (-10.622) (-7.91)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is ... unhelpful.

Your problem is that you're mixing numeric and character data in a column.  The `dat` variables are numeric.

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("dat")), 
                 funs( case_when(name == 't_stat' ~ paste0("(", ., ")"),
                                 TRUE ~ as.character(.))))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
   dep   name     dat1     dat2      dat3    
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   
 1 cyl   estimate 1.151    1.274     1.078   
 2 cyl   t_stat   (6.686)  (8.423)   (5.191) 
 3 disp  estimate 102.902  106.429   103.687 
 4 disp  t_stat   (12.107) (12.148)  (7.79)  
 5 drat  estimate -0.422   -0.394    -0.194  
 6 drat  t_stat   (-5.237) (-5.304)  (-2.629)
 7 hp    estimate 37.576   38.643    36.777  
 8 hp    t_stat   (5.067)  (6.172)   (4.842) 
 9 mpg   estimate -5.057   -4.843    -4.539  
10 mpg   t_stat   (-8.185) (-10.622) (-7.91)
```